# Counting multidimensional array values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, count

I have an array called $people that looks like the following:

```
Array
(
    [541377306] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6248267085
        )

    [731082330] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6248267085
            [1] => 229668807087652
        )

    [742088719] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6248267085
        )

    [1133688950] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6248267085
        )

)
```

You'll see that [731082330] has more values than the rest. How could I have counted that? This seems like it should be easy but none of the examples I can find around the place really match my kind of array. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to count the 2 values of of 731082330? or just the first one?

Comment: What's the kind of condition you wish to make with this? Find the array key with the most values inside?

Comment: I want to be able to output the one with the most number of values, echo $mostvalues would give me 731082330. I'm looking through the responses now.

Comment: What if there are two elements that both have 2 values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. This is what did it.

```
//count values
$count = array_map('count', $people);

//find highest
$value =  max($count);

//find value for highest
$mostvalues = array_search($value, $count);

echo $mostvalues;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you can do it. However, just a small hint. This should work.

```
foreach ($array1 as $array2){ // array1 contains multiple arrays inside it
            echo count($array2);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a regular `count()` to each element:

```
$count = array_map('count', $people);

echo $count['731082330']; // 2
```

This can be sorted and the first key can be picked, assuming you don't care about more than one element having the most values:

```
arsort($count);
echo key($count);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
  echo count($value) . "<br />";
}
```

Try this